# Setting left border of TD to a colour, but not have it lodged to left of Header row?

Tags: css

I want to define the colour of the left border of a  cell within a table, normally the code would look like:

```
border-left: solid 10px red;
```

However this border is created to the left of the TD, so the Header cells are now not level, probably because these header cells do not have the same left border.

Is there is way to set a left border within the TD, something like setting the colour of a padding-left or margin-left, so that the borders remain aligned.

Thanks,

EDIT

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <th style="border-left:solid 10px transparent">Col1 heading</th>
  <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td style="border-left:solid 10px red">Col1 value<td/>
     <td>Col2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above

Comment: Why not just give the header cells the same border? border-color could be transparent, if you don’t want it to actually show …

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS, so someone here can help you debug.

Comment: as @CBroe says, just use `transparent` instead of `red` on the sides you don't want any color. Then they will remain level.

Comment: I did try my edit on its own and its seems to work, whereas my ASP.NET page HTML seems to put the border, half in and half out the <TD>. So this could be an issue of polluting CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header cell CSS:

```
border-left: solid 10px transparent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
border-top: solid 10px transparent;
border-right: solid 10px transparent;
border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
border-left: solid 10px red;
```